# Unable to run boost unit tests

Tags: macos, unit-testing, boost, homebrew

so I am trying to run a program and It is showing Me this error. I am using Mac Pro and I installed boost via home-brew (brew install boost)

```
library not found for -lboost_unit_test_frameworktype here
```

My test file is this:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE ComplexTest
#include "Real.hpp"
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(TestAdd)
{
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(Real(2) + Real(2), Real(4));
}
```

I also tried this and it is still failing:

```
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test_framework.hpp>
```

What should I do?

Comment: "library not found" - the library isn't found. Perhaps you need to make the name more specific for the platform or add the library paths

Comment: @sehe Ok, I added this line in LIB and I think it found it (LIB = -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.82.0_1/include -o prog -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.82.0_1/lib/ -lboost_unit_test_framework) but it is still giving me this error(Test.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'boost/test/unit_test.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>) Sorry, but I am still a beginner so I am trying to understand how things work out.